# deep debug/monitoring LSI RAID cotroller

Tags: hardware-raid, debug

I happen to be I stile use LSI RAID controller for Lustre file system in Centos 5. Sometimes Lustre have file system have failure. In my opinion it can be connected with working LSI RAID controller 9260. But in logs I cant saw some failures. May be it connected with sometimes hang controller.

Can I get more monitoring events or resources for control to RAID controller ? I mean something like see flags in pci space or something like msr registers or kind of this.

May be anybody get me direct of my findings ?